# unity interception from config without using container

Tags: c#, unity-container, ioc-container, unity-interception

Hi I am trying to use unity interception (I don't want to use unity container).
I am able to configure run time but don't know how to configure it from config.

my code:

```
public interface ICalculator
{
    int Add(int first, int second);

    int Multiply(int first, int second);
}
```

Behavior:

```
  internal class LogBehavior : IInterceptionBehavior 
    {
        public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
        {
            // My Code
            IMethodReturn result = getNext()(input, getNext);
            return result;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Type> GetRequiredInterfaces()
        {
            return Type.EmptyTypes;
        }

        public bool WillExecute {
            get { return true; }
        }
    }
```

And this is how I am calling it

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var calculator = new Calculator();
        var calculatorProxy = Intercept.ThroughProxy<ICalculator>(calculator,
          new InterfaceInterceptor(), new[] { new LogBehavior() });
        Console.WriteLine(calculatorProxy.Add(2, 2));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

This is working. I need to configure this from config file.
Please help

Comment: Have you tried to do what is at that url: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660932%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the container, you'll have to do the proxy instanciation yourself. That's the `Intercept.ThroughProxy<>` call. If you're using another container, you could extend it to read the config and handle it accordingly.

But there's no magic where you can just have .net / unity read the config file and just do `new Calculator()` and `Calculator` will be proxied and intercepted with the interceptors defined in the config file. `new` can't be extended to handle that and as such there will always be some component you'll have to ask for an instance of `ICalculator`, which will then check whether it needs to be proxied and which interceptors it needs...

Of course, there's an exception to this. If you use weaving ([Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody), [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/)) you can do AOP without using dynamic proxies. And then, you can actually do `new Calculator()` and it will have it's aspects, not only its core implementation...